# What is a magic with 5 lines of code in htaccess?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, coding-style

I want to know, with this code in `.htaccess`

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
```

Can do many things on query strings from URLs like Wordpres have done by example. It's depend on our coding or.. ? What is the secret ingredients to make like that?

Let me know if you have a good source to share with me. All in one.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This would make some kind of catch all page.

Let's explain it line by line

```
RewriteEngine On
```

enable mod rewrite

```
RewriteBase /
```

Set the base url of the rules to '/'

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
```

if the requested file doesn't exist (i.e not a jpg)

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
```

if the requested directory doesn't exist

```
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
```

Redirect everything to index.php

So to summarize it will redirect any URL to index.php if the filename or directory requested doesn't exist.

and the [documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/misc/rewriteguide.html) if you want to do some more reading.

Answer (score 2):

The **[rewrite engine](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_rewrite.html)** makes it possible to match paths and do manipulations, redirects etc. based on advanced rules.

Your specific example sets up two [conditions](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond) (path must not represent an existing regular file nor directory) and then redirects anything else to `index.php`. You can then implement whatever you wish in `index.php` in order to match and/or parse the original request (e.g., `/news/some-title` could be forwarded to the news module where the news item can be fetched via the [slug](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slug_%28web_publishing%29)).

Sometimes you will see the initial <strike>redirect</strike> rewrite(s) done directly in `.htaccess`. The above could look like:

```
RewriteRule ^news/(.+)$ newsview.php?title=$1 [QSA,L]
```